# Databricks truncating results to 1000 columns

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have been trying to `printSchema()` of a `Dataframe` in `Databricks`. The Dataframe has more than 1500 columns and apparently Databricks is truncating results and displaying only 1000 items. How to output more than 1000 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limit is not the number of rows, but on the size of the output - if I remember correctly, it's 64k.

Databricks also shows the schema of the Dataframe when it's created - click on the icon next to the name of variable that holds the dataframe (it still should be limited to the max output size - I was able to see table schema with up to 1900 columns):

[image]

If you have output of more than limit, then I would imagine outputting the schema into file, with something like this, and then opening the file with some editor:

```py
v = df._jdf.schema().treeString()
with open("/dbfs/mnt/.....", "w") as file:
  file.write(v)
```

Comment: I can't even find the source of the `display` function...
Anyway. The limit may be on the size of the output but in practice it's the 1000 rows that you get to see. Now there is also an option to re-execute with maximum result limits. This sometimes works, but not always. Best would be to have a display iterator, so that at each evaluation you get the next 1000 lines.

Comment: Ask your databricks representative to follow up with product manager. Also, question wasn’t about display function…

Comment: Thanks Alex. You're right. The question is about the columns. Not the rows.