# Why does Databricks only plot 1000 rows?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks, gcp-databricks

Is there any way in Databricks to plot more than 1000 rows with the built in visualization?
I tried using `limit()` function, but it still shows only the first 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible right now.  `limit` won't help because it limits the amount of data in the dataframe itself, but `display` function has its own parameters.

Comment: - If you really want to see more than 1000 rows result , @Alex's such a fantastic answer here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68093283/databricks-truncating-results-to-1000-columns